# Alias a column when querying a content provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am trying to display custom suggestions in a Search Dialog when the user search for a contact. The custom suggestions require a Content Provider to return a column with one of its columns named as `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1`.

I am querying the Contacts provider declaring the projection as follows:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{Contacts._ID,Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1};
```

But this is throwing the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column display_name AS suggest_text_1
```

I have been researching and this is due to the Contacts provider sets `strictProjectionMap` flag in their `SQLiteQueryBuilder`, so I am wondering if someone has a workaround to be able to specify an alias. I found several solutions but those require to modify the content provider and in this case it is not possible because it is an Android provider.

If it is not possible what is  a best practice for this scenario? My current solution is to create a `MatrixCursor` with the right column names and copy all the values from the cursor returned from the query to the Contacts provider but it feels very wrong in terms of efficiency so I think there might be a better way.

Thanks for your suggestions.
Juan

Comment: I am also getting an error trying to alias a column.  I am getting this error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "as" when trying to alias the "date" column of the "content://mms-sms/conversations/" content provider.